# ReferenceError: gtag is not defined

Tags: javascript, angular, e-commerce, google-tag-manager

Here is the head script

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
  <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','xxxxxxxx');</script>
  <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

and body script

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=xxxxxxx"
  height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
  <!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
```

xxxxxxx is instead of the ID

and htis is app.ts code which makes the problem

```
this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
        if(event instanceof NavigationEnd){
            gtag('config', 'xxxxxx',
                  {
                    'page_path': event.urlAfterRedirects
                  }
                 );
         }
      });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `window.gtag`

Comment: where should I write?

Comment: `gtag` to `window.gtag`

Comment: it gives me that

   gtag doesn't exist in window

Comment: The script you provided seems like a "GTM" script. It's different from "gtag" script.
Or you need to create a html custom script tag and paste the gtag script in it with all pageview trigger.

Comment: @Darrellwan, can you please help me how to create a html custom script tag? Or elaborate what are you trying to say?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61041158/google-analytics-webapp-event-config-error-gtag-is-not-defined