# Error: gtag is not defined in angular 8 project

Tags: google-analytics, angular8

I'm working in angular 8 and added google analytics in order to lend better services to the user. but it is continuously showing the following error:[image: gtag error]

Following is service added to use google analytics in the project:

```
gaservice.service.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

declare let gtag:Function;
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GoogleAnalyticsService {
  constructor(){}

  public eventEmitter( 
    eventCategory: string, 
    eventAction: string, 
    eventLabel: string = null,  
    eventValue: number = null ){ 
               gtag('event', eventAction, {
                'event_category': eventCategory,
                'event_label': eventLabel,
                'value': eventValue
              });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

`(<any>window).gtag(..)`

or

`window['gtag'](...)`

I think what I may do is create a function:

```
export const gtag = () => window['dataLayer'].push(arguments)
```

This is because I'm using GTM with GA4 but it doesn't define `window.gtag` for me (See [Google Analytics Web+App event config: Error 'gtag is not defined'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61041158/google-analytics-webapp-event-config-error-gtag-is-not-defined)).

Comment: I do not understand this solution, where do I put this line of code? If I put it instead of "declare let gtag:Function;", I get error for arguments and then the params list for gtag. Pleas help!

Comment: The line of code `export const gtag...` you would put anywhere and import it when you need to push to the data layer. I know tag manager is always a pain!