# Why am I getting gtag is not defined with GTM script

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, gtag.js

I have an issue that I believe just started happening and we didn't change anything with website that would affect this that I know of.  It used to work and I double checked in the Tag manager portal the ID we use is still valid and accurate on https://tagmanager.google.com/....

VM16:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: gtag is not defined
at :1:1
at www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=******&l=MaterionData:309:414
at www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=******&l=MaterionData:310:118
at c (www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=*******&l=MaterionData:311:160)
at qc (www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=******&l=MaterionData:47:19)
at e (www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=******&l=MaterionData:151:278)
at www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=*******&l=MaterionData:31:130
at Array. (www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=******&l=MaterionData:152:370)
at Object.execute (www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=*******&l=MaterionData:152:110)
at ak (www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=******&l=MaterionData:152:845)

Here is our server side rendering code

```
if (Model.CustomDimensionDictionary != null && Model.CustomDimensionDictionary.Count > 0)
{
    <script>
     @foreach (var customDimension in Model.CustomDimensionDictionary)
     {
         @:MaterionData = [{'dimension3': '@customDimension.Value'}];
     }
    </script>
}

<script>
    (function (w, d, s, l, i) {
        w[l] = w[l] || []; w[l].push({
            'gtm.start':
                new Date().getTime(), event: 'gtm.js'
        }); var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
            j = d.createElement(s), dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : ''; j.async = true; j.src =
            'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl; f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
    })(window, document, 'script', 'MaterionData', '@Model.MainSiteNode.GoogleAnalyticsPropertyId');

</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

```
<noscript>
    <iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=*******"
            height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>
</noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
```

Comment: looks like your log doesn't have the GTM ID. Either you've removed it from the log and didn't mention it, or you have issues with your `@Model.MainSiteNode.GoogleAnalyticsPropertyId` Either way, you can continue debugging by grabbing the GTM url and loading it with JS, inspecting what's in it. Also, noscript has no value, you can remove it from the source/dom.

Comment: I removed it to hide it. On google site they tell you to use the <noscript> in the instructions.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61041158/google-analytics-webapp-event-config-error-gtag-is-not-defined and at the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked at link BNazaruk sent and then added these two lines just before the  tag in header and now it works:

window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}